# Why do std classes not use static_assert on non-copyable types?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, static-assert

Why does the std library not use these instead? Currently if a call is made to the copy constructor on a non-copyable object, the error message can be a little 'cryptic' or confusing to someone who has never encountered one before.

The first time I had this error message I had no idea what the problem was (I never thought of the idea of inaccessible ctors) until I looked up the class and saw "non-copyable" and finally understood.

what were the benefits of making the copy-ctor private? It is still visible in VS intellisense for ctor overloads.

why did they not simply choose to:

```
public:
someClass(const someClass&) { static_assert(false, "someClass is of non-copyable type. calls to copy constructor are disallowed."); }
```

if someone tries to compile their code they will see this error message, which states the reason of the error more explicitly. Compared to (const someClass&) is inaccessible. Imagine how difficult it would be to understand this when heavy use of templates are involved?

so, what benefits are there to a private copy-ctor vs a static_assert?

Comment: static_assert is available since C++11. Probably the std library was written using C++03.

Comment: How exactly do you expect this to work? The class won't compile, no matter what. The `static_assert` is checked by trying to compile the class code, not by calling it.

Comment: it works on VS2012. unordered_map also uses it when a type without a hashing function is provided. The class compiles on my end, it only fails when I call copy-ctor or assignment.

Comment: @David: If you are using it in a template, then it works because VS [doesn't properly implement two-phase look-up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273176/what-exactly-is-broken-with-microsoft-visual-cs-two-phase-template-instanti). And no, `unordered_map` doesn't do what you are doing. It doesn't pass `false` directly to `static_assert`. It passes a value that is computed based on the key.

Comment: Here's a more relevant link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The reason of cryptic messages is a problem of compiler, not C++, although that's true that for C++ implementing good messages is harder.
   Clang provides much better error messages than other compilers, for
   example.
2. I don't know why MS decided to show private overloads in
   VS intellisense - but that's definitely not a С++ problem but
   a problem of IDE (or there is some hidden, unknown for me sense).
3. static_assert is supported only in C++11 and it
   would require to change even more standard specs just to change
   error message.
4. Private constructor is more idiomatic in C++ than
   custom static_asserts.
5. This suggestion doesn't even make any sense. The static_assert will cause a compiler error. Always. Whether anyone tries to call the copy constructor or not. (As pointed out by @BenjaminLindley in comments)

Comment: fair enough, for older libraries this makes sense, but for thread, future, packaged_task, and promise, it would be reasonable to implement a static_assert instead, since they are all apart of c++11

Comment: 5. This suggestion doesn't even make any sense. The `static_assert` will cause a compiler error. Always. Whether anyone tries to call the copy constructor or not.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 there is a better way:

```
someClass(const someClass&) = delete;
```

Unfortunately, MSVC does not support it yet.

But, maybe [there is hope](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-9-of-n):

> Yep, I was super busy getting the STL ready for VS 2013 Preview. I've
>   got a VCBlog draft with a detailed changelog that I'll be able to
>   publish after the Build conference.