# static_assert even if member is not instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

When putting a with a hardcoded value, it is triggered even if the function it's in isn't instantiated. Is this behavior correct or do I misunderstand how static assert works?

```
#include <type_traits>
template <class T>
struct Helper
{
    static void do_something()
    {
        // Always fails, even when not instantiated.
        static_assert(false,
            "You must specialize this class to serialize Enums.");

        // Work around:
        static_assert(!std::is_same<T, T>::value,
            "You must specialize this class to serialize Enums.");
    }
};
```

Using: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

Comment: Hmm, yea: is a dup.... Should I delete it?

Comment: @nishantjr: We'll close it, no prob.

Answer (score 0):

SFINAE works for function arguments and return type, not template parameters.

Comment: Sorry, don't thing SFINAE is relevant. Revised to give a more minimal example

Answer (score 0):

That is because "false" does not depend on the template in any way, for the compiler this code is sure to assert. There is similar thread

[static_assert fails compilation even though template function is called nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere)