# Specialize member function of a templated derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following code (very simplified for the sake of clarity):

```
class Base
{
    virtual int DoStuff(int arg) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
    int DoStuff(int arg) override
    {
         // do some stuff
         return 0;
    }
};
```

This works great. Now I want to implement a special (vectorized) implementation of DoStuff. And I need the implementation to be specific based on the type T that Derived has, something like this:

```
class Base
{
    virtual int DoStuff(int arg) = 0;
    virtual int DoStuffVectorized(int arg) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
    int DoStuff(int arg) override
    {
         // do some stuff
         return 0;
    }

    int DoStuffVectorized<char>(int arg) override
    {
         // do some stuff for T == char
         return 0;
    }

    int DoStuffVectorized<int>(int arg) override
    {
         // do some stuff for T == int
         return 0;
    }
};
```

However i'm unable to make this work.

**EDIT:**
I get the following error message: error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' on the line `int DoStuffVectorized<char>(int arg) override`.

When i change it to:
`template<char> int DoStuffVectorized(int arg) override` i get: error C2898: ...': member function templates cannot be virtual

Any advice on how to achieve something like this? The reason i need it is that i have a std::vector that stores data of various types (by using Derived<>). This way i can use the same simple code regardless of the type being stored and i want this to be true even when using the special vectorized implementation of DoStuff that is sadly type specific.

Comment: What does "I'm unable to make it work" mean?

Comment: "However i'm unable to make this work" Why? Any error messages? What is not working?

Comment: Added error messages. It seems to me that i'm getting lost in some inheritance/template definition syntax errors?

Comment: But where is inheritance you haven't shown any relationship between derived and base

Comment: @PeterK `Derived` doesn't inherit from `Base`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specialize template member functions outside of the class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public:
    virtual int DoStuffVectorized(int arg) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    int DoStuffVectorized(int arg) override;
};

template <>
int Derived<char>::DoStuffVectorized(int arg)
{
     std::cout <<  "T == char\n";
     return 0;
}

template <>
int Derived<int>::DoStuffVectorized(int arg)
{
     std::cout <<  "T == int\n";
     return 0;
}

int main(){
    Derived<char> c;
    Derived<int> i;
    Base* b[] = { &c, &i };
    for(auto* x : b)
        x->DoStuffVectorized(0);
    // undefined reference to `Derived<double>::DoStuffVectorized(int)'
    // Derived<double> d;
}
```

If you want to capture unintended instantiations at compile time:

```
#include <type_traits>

// A std::false_type (useful in a static_assert)
template <typename T>
struct static_false : std::false_type
{};

template <typename T>
int Derived<T>::DoStuffVectorized(int arg)
{
    static_assert(static_false<T>::value, "Neither 'char' or 'int'");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't you think we should have one mone generic overload for DoStuffVectorized otherwise something like Derived <float> f will not work

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i want!

Comment: But why to complicate stuff with std::false_type why not directly use static_assert(false, "Neither 'char' or 'int'");

Comment: @Kapil The compiler will see a not (template) deduced 'false', which will always cause an assertion (even for 'char' and 'int')

Comment: Ok i can see there will be error if we use false directly but could not understand why compiler is going to this generic function even for char and int

Comment: Got the answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere

Answer (score 2):

`DoStuffVectorized<char>` is not correct syntax, `DoStuffVectorized` isn't template itself.

See [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
    int DoStuff(int arg) override
    {
         // do some stuff
         return 0;
    }
    int DoStuffVectorized(int arg) override
    {
         // do some stuff (primary template)
         return 0;
    }
};

template <>
int Derived<int>::DoStuffVectorized(int) {
     // do some stuff for T == char
     return 0;
}

template <>
int Derived<char>::DoStuffVectorized(int) {
     // do some stuff for T == char
     return 0;
}
```