# Automatic type deduction using is_same_v

Tags: c++, templates

I have some code in a template like so:

```
if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, CompletedGeneration> ) {
    auto stat = stats->getGenerationStats();
} else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, CompletedReset> ) {
    auto stat = stats->getResetStats();
} else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, CompletedRun> ) {
    auto stat = stats->getRunStats();
} else {
    static_assert( false, "Invalid type for helper function" );
}
```

The `auto` for `stat` was just to get it to compile temporarily. `stats` is of type `T`

After this if-statement, there's a bunch of code which relies on `stat`, so obviously I can't define it in the `if` portion. I'm wondering, how would I go about defining it outside of the `if`, since its type is dependent on the template parameter type `T` (but is not a `T` itself)?

Would I have to specify an additional template parameter `U`, which takes in the type for `stat`? Or have to use some sort of inheritance? Both of these options I'd rather avoid.

Comment: The easiest solution might be to refactor the "bunch of code which relies on `stat`" to a function template that can take different types of `stat`s.

Comment: @0x5453, I was also thinking of a second template helper like that (this template function is just a helper to reduce duplication).

Comment: `stats` is of type `T` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, yes, sorry. Should have included that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could wrap it in an immediately invoked lambda expression

```
auto stat = [&] {
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, CompletedGeneration> ) {
        return stats->getGenerationStats();
    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, CompletedReset> ) {
        return stats->getResetStats();
    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, CompletedRun> ) {
        return stats->getRunStats();
    }
}();
```

This also eliminates the need for the [ill-advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere) `static_assert(false)`, which is now replaced by `stat` having the invalid type of `void`.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly … need to remember to use lambdas more.

Comment: I've seen a few devs emphasizing the call operator not to confuse fast reader who could think `stat` is a lambda. `auto stat = [] { /* ...*/ }(); // IILE`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a type trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct stats_type;

template <>
struct stat_type<CompletedGeneration> {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().getGenerationStats());
};

// and similar for the other cases
```

The correct type for `stat` is then just `stat_type<T>::type;`

However, this is perhaps a bit old-school and too much boilerplate. I just wanted to mention it for the sake of completeness. On the other hand if you wrap the corresponding function call in the constructor of `stat_type` then you can replace your whole `constexpr if-else` with a single line of `stats_type<T>::type stat{stats};`.