# Is this use of static_assert inside if constexpr well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, static-assert, if-constexpr

I read a couple of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304847/constexpr-if-and-static-assert) yesterday, on the use of `static_assert(false, "Some message")` inside the `else` clause of an `if constexpr`. I understand that it's considered to be *ill-formed*, according to the standard (even if some compilers, including MSVC2017, will accept it). Qt will also mark this as an error.

My question is, is the code below *well-formed* according to the standard? (I'm inclined to think so, but I'd like a confirmation.)

```
template <typename TypeOfValue>
static void PushValue(duk_context* ctx, TypeOfValue value) {
    // Push value onto duktape stack
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TypeOfValue, int>::value) {
        // Push int
        duk_push_int(ctx, value);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same<TypeOfValue, uint32_t>::value) {
        // Push uint
        duk_push_uint(ctx, value);
    } else {
        // Unsupported type
        static_assert(bool_value<false, TypeOfValue>(), "Unsupported type");
    }    
}

template <bool value, typename T>
static constexpr bool bool_value() {return value;}
```

**Edit**:

It seems, from the comment I got, that *bool_value* should instead be defined like this:

```
template<bool value, typename T>
struct bool_value { 
    static constexpr bool value = value; 
};
```

with the usage pattern

```
// Unsupported type
static_assert(bool_value<false, TypeOfValue>::value, "Unsupported type");
```

It's then well-formed, only because it's possible for *bool_value* to be specialized into a version which returns *true* for the expression `bool_value<false, TypeOfValue>::value`.

Comment: [cppreference reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If): "the discarded statement can't be ill-formed for every possible specialization". But `bool_value<false, TypeOfValue>()` is `false` for every possible specialization.

Comment: I remember a discussion after one of C++ conference presentations (I don't remember which one, sorry) about such code. The outcome was something like this: practically, this always works, but theoretically, this is still ill-formed, because `bool_value<false, TypeOfValue>::value` is always `false` unless you actually have a specialization that returns `true` (e.g. `std::is_void_t<TypeOfValue>`). Consider adding the [tag:language-lawyer] tag to your question.

Comment: If i get what you're trying to do, i would elevate the check into the immediate context of the template. I can conjure up a godbolt if you want.

Comment: @Taekahn The goal is to get a compiler error if I use the template with the wrong parameters. I know it can be solved in other ways (separate overloaded functions, for instance), but I'm looking for a judgement on this particular way of doing it.

Comment: @Elling I would just use the exact example from cppreference then. It's a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your attempts (with the function and with the struct) are well-formed as is.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62469617/2752075) mentions [`[temp.res]/8`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8), but I disagree with how it was interpreted.

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. ... The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or ...

Both the function and struct you wrote *can* be specialized to be `true`. I believe the mere possibility of specialization is enough, you don't actually need to add a dummy `true` specialization to make the code well-formed.

According to my understanding (and according to common sense, I hope), the point of this part of the standard is to allow compilers to check validity of templates and `if constexpr` branches early (when they are seen for the first time), and reject the ones that can't possibly be instantiated.

Every branch in your template *can* potentially be instantiated, because `bool_value()` *can* be specialized later. I doubt a sane compiler is going to reject your code due to `bool_value()` not being specialized *yet*.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317834/4944425) of the question you linked explains why it's ill-formed. Note the quote from the Standard [temp.res-8](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8), which says (emphasis mine)

> The validity of a template **may** be checked prior to any instantiation. [...] The program is ill-formed, **no diagnostic required**, if:
>
> - no valid specialization **can be generated** for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or...
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, no diagnostic shall be issued for a template for which a valid specialization **can be generated**.
> [ *Note:* If a template is instantiated, errors will be diagnosed according to the other rules in this document.
> Exactly when these errors are diagnosed is a quality of implementation issue.
> — *end note*
> ]

In the cppreference [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) about `if` you can see the following workaround (emphasis mine)

> The common workaround for such a catch-all statement is a **type-dependent** expression that is always false:
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};
> template <typename T>
> void f() {
>      if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
>          // ...
>      else
>        static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "Must be arithmetic"); // ok
> }
> ```

As noted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg) by [Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg)

> theoretically, this is still ill-formed, because [...] is always `false` unless you actually have a specialization that returns true.

So you could add that specialization to the previous snippet

```
namespace {
    // Do not unleash.
    struct aggressive_unicorn_type;
}

template<> struct dependent_false<aggressive_unicorn_type> : std::true_type {};
```

Whether this is necessary to satisfy the Standard document to the letter or not it depends on the interpretation of *"**can** be generated"*.

I wonder if it really matters too. The OP is asking if the code is well-formed, but they are actually trying to produce a code which is ill-formed, with a diagnostic (that's what `static_assert(false)` implies, see [dcl.pre](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.pre-6)) under certain conditions.

As the asker already noted, there are other methods to force a compiler error when arguments of the "wrong" type are passed (consider concepts, of the upcoming standard) and, maybe, if we want to use `static_assert`s in conjunction with `if constexpr` the best option may be a type-dependent expression that is *not* always false.

```
#include <type_traits>

void f(int) {};
void g(unsigned) {};

template< class T>
constexpr inline bool is_supported =
    std::is_same_v<T, int> ||
    std::is_same_v<T, unsigned> ||
    std::is_same_v<T, char>;

template <class T>
void use(T value) {
    static_assert(is_supported<T>, "Not supported");
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
        f(value);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, unsigned>){
        g(value);
    } else {
        static_assert( !is_supported<T>, "Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add my own final thoughts as an answer, <s>since I seem to not be getting a quite principled enough answer from other sources</s>.

My conclusion after reading a couple of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere) answers is this:

1. The compiler is allowed, according to the standard, to evaluate `static_assert(false, "...")` early. If it does, it produces a program that can never compile.
2. A program that can never compile is ill-formed.

So, the problem is that the compiler is allowed to evaluate static_assert early, even within an `if constexpr`.

Forcing it to delay the evaluation until instantiation time, by introducing a `false` that artificially depends upon a template parameter, seems a bit contrived to me. But I accept that there are other considerations which probably makes it the correct language choice anyway. (That's the sort of thing I was hoping for an expert answer to shed some light upon.)