# Using trailing return type to prevent function template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, trailing-return-type, template-instantiation

While toying with crude reproductions of some of C++17 `if constexpr` functionalities, I encountered an issue where using `auto` seems to trigger the instantiation of a template.

The function template in question contains an assertion which fails as expected when its parameters have certain properties (say sizeof).

In C++17 you could trivially use the `if constexpr` to protect against instantiating the wrong template in favor of a more appropriate one. This is the behavior I seek to reproduce. And I would like to understand why the trailing return type of the `Working()` template below does the *trick* but not the `NotWorking()` template.

The code is available at: https://godbolt.org/z/7he9hPMaM

As noted @LanguageLawyer, the code can be further reduced to:

```
template <typename T>
auto* NotWorking() {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 4, "");
    return static_cast<T*>(nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
auto Working() -> T* {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 4, "");
    return static_cast<T*>(nullptr);
}

#define PRODUCE_ERROR

template <typename T>
void not_called_closure_operator(T) {
#if defined(PRODUCE_ERROR)
    NotWorking<long>();
#else
    Working<long>();
#endif
}
```

Code available at: https://godbolt.org/z/oGqb5v9j4

Comment: What about explicitly returning `T*` in the non-trailing way? Should have the same effect as trailing.

Comment: For some convoluted reasons in the *real* code. This above is a reproducer of the issue. Trailing return type or not, why `auto*` or `auto` breaks the compilation ?

Comment: Doesn't https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#8.1 apply to the closure type's `operator()` template?

Comment: As noted by @LanguageLawyer this appears to be IFNDR. In practice, the use of `auto` with no trailing return type means that the compiler must instantiate the function to determine the return type. Instantiation is not required if you use an explicit return type (either leading or trailing).

Comment: Dup of [static\_assert fails compilation even though template function is called nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere)

Comment: All the question machinery essentially minimizes to smth like https://godbolt.org/z/Pz37hnzYP

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Indeed the resulting issue is similar to [static_assert fails compilation even though template function is called nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637356/static-assert-fails-compilation-even-though-template-function-is-called-nowhere) but it may be unexpected that `auto` triggers this kind of behavior so I would not mark it as duplicate.
Thanks for the info details @RaymondChen.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer @OP You should expect similar result with using `auto` return (no trailing return type) vs templated type. However, the linked dup failed to compile because no valid specializations can be generated, which is not the case for OP.