# Why is always_false_v required in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

I'm using `std::variant` to specify the types of properties that an entity in my project may have, and stumbled upon [this code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) from cppreference:

```
std::visit([](auto&& arg)
        {
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
                std::cout << "int with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)
                std::cout << "long with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
                std::cout << "double with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
                std::cout << "std::string with value " << std::quoted(arg) << '\n';
            else 
                static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
        }, w);
```

`always_false_v` is defined as

```
template<class>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;
```

I get that this checks at compile time if I'm handling all of the types in my variant which is pretty cool and helpful, but I'm puzzled as to why `always_false_v<T>` is required.

If I remove a branch from the `if`s, intellisense in Visual Studio immediately sets red squigglies because the `static_assert` fails.

If I replace `always_false_v<T>` with `false`, intellisense doesn't complain but the static assert fails when I try to build.

Why is just `false` not enough? I would expect the `else` to never execute even at compile time, if it executes all the time, why is `always_false_v<T>` not equivalent to `false` (it looks like it's `true` which surely it cannot be)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637356/481267). [Jonathan Wakely's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14637534/481267) is particularly informative.

In short, because `static_assert(false)` makes the program ill-formed, if you place `static_assert(false)` in a template or in a branch of an `if constexpr` statement, then it means that every possible instantiation of that template or that `if constexpr` branch will make the program ill-formed. When the compiler sees a template or an `if constexpr` branch that where every possible instantiation is ill-formed, it can reject the program even if such instantiations never occur.

However, when you have a construct of the form `static_assert(always_false_v<T>);`, it is not true that every possible instantiation makes it ill-formed. There could be some specialization of `always_false_v` that is true. Sure, in your program, you don't have such a specialization, but the point is that you *could* introduce one, and it could be after the definition of the template that references it. Because `static_assert(always_false<T>)` does not satisfy the "no possible instantiation could be well-formed" criterion, it avoids the problem of `static_assert(false)`.

The fact that `static_assert(false)` makes the entire template ill-formed is particularly annoying, as there's no situation where the early diagnosis is actually helpful to the programmer. For this reason, the rules have been changed in C++23 to provide a special exemption for static assertions: `static_assert(false)` will now only make the program ill-formed if it is actually instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

`static_assert(false, ...)` is always evaluated, so will always fail immediately. You need the 1st parameter to be dependant on template evaluation so it get evaluated only if the other `if` branches evaluate as false.

See Raymond Chen's blog article on this topic for a deeper explanation:

[How can I create a type-dependent expression that is always false?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553)

In a nutshell:

> One of the things I had to do was prevent compilation from succeeding if the lambda was called incorrectly. I had a chain of `if constexpr` tests for the valid cases, and I needed to put a `static_assert` in the `else` that said “You should never get here.”
>
> ...
>
> However, this does not compile because [`static_assert(false,...)`] fails immediately.
>
> The reason is that the controlling expression for the `static_assert` is not dependent upon the type of the arguments, and therefore it is evaluated when the lambda is compiled, not when the lambda is invoked (and the implicit template instantiated).
>
> In order to defer the `static_assert` to instantiation, we need to make it type-dependent.